# How to sync Notification builder and alarm manager?

Tags: java, android, notifications, alarmmanager, notificationmanager

Every time i set an alarm/notification. The notification builder triggers immediately s and I have no idea how to set a 'delay' to match the alarm manager.

Although its working 'properly'. It pops at the right time when the alarm manager was set.

onReceive()

```
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent intentToStartWhenAlarmSets = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
    intentToStartWhenAlarmSets.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    //I commented this part because i thought if i use the same pending intent ('pi'), they would sync.
    //PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 103, intentToStartWhenAlarmSets, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentIntent(pi)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Content Title")
            .setContentText("Notify " + intent.getStringExtra("medicine"))
            .setSound(notifSound)
            //.setVibrate(pattern)
            //swipable

            .setAutoCancel(true);

    Log.d(TAG, "onReceive INTENT: " + intent.getStringExtra("medicine") + " " + intent.getStringExtra("interval"));

    notificationManager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), builder.build());
```

Method for  setting an alarm

```
public void setAlarm(Context context, int hour, int min, int notifyID) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
    Log.d(TAG, "setAlarm: " + hour + ":" + min);

    if (calendar.getTimeInMillis() < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
        Log.d(TAG, "setAlarm: PAST SO + 1 DAY");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "setAlarm: FUTURE DON'T DO ANYTHING");
    }

    am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, notifyID, _intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    //params alarm type, trigger time, interval, pending intent
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * (_interval * 3600), pi);
    Log.d(TAG, "setAlarm: " + calendar.getTimeInMillis() + _interval);
}
```

Both are in the same receiver class.

Manifest

```
 <receiver android:name=".NotificationReceiver"/>
```

Here is the full code.

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    //PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    //PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
    //wl.acquire();

    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.layout_notification);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.txtNotifMeds, "please work");
    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imgNotif, R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    long[] pattern = {500, 500};
    //default ringtone
    Uri notifSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: its working");
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent intentToStartWhenAlarmSets = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
    intentToStartWhenAlarmSets.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);


    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Content Title")
            .setContentText("Notify " + intent.getStringExtra("medicine"))
            .setSound(notifSound)
            //.setVibrate(pattern)
            //swipable
            .setAutoCancel(true);


    Log.d(TAG, "onReceive INTENT: " + intent.getStringExtra("medicine") + " " + intent.getStringExtra("interval"));
    notificationManager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), builder.build());

    //wl.release();
    Log.d(TAG, "life cycle check: onReceive");
}

//init
private Intent _intent;
private PendingIntent pi;
private AlarmManager am;
private int _interval;
private boolean setNotif;
private int _notifyID;

public void setNotifData(Context context, String medicine, String interval,String uid) {
    //initialize intent
    _intent = new Intent(context, NotificationReceiver.class);
    //
    _intent.putExtra("medicine", medicine);
    _intent.putExtra("interval", interval);
    _intent.putExtra("uid", uid);
    _interval = Integer.parseInt(_intent.getStringExtra("interval"));
    context.sendBroadcast(_intent);
    Log.d(TAG, "setNotifData: " + medicine);
}

public void setAlarm(Context context, int hour, int min, int notifyID) {
    _notifyID = notifyID;
    Log.d(TAG, "setAlarm: notify ID " + notifyID);
    //Log.d(TAG, "setAlarm: isAlarmSet " + isAlarmSet(context));

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
    Log.d(TAG, "setAlarm: " + hour + ":" + min);

    if (calendar.getTimeInMillis() < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
        Log.d(TAG, "setAlarm: PAST SO + 1 DAY");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "setAlarm: FUTURE DON'T DO ANYTHING");
    }

    am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, notifyID, _intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    //params alarm type,
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * (_interval * 30), pi);

    Log.d(TAG, "setAlarm: calendarMills" + calendar.getTimeInMillis() +  " Interval: " +_interval);
    Log.d(TAG, "life cycle check: set alarm ");
}

//ToDo need to add alarm != null checker in fragment.
//ToDo still need to fix alarm setting immediately.
public void cancelNotification(Context context, int notifyID) {
    Intent intentCancel = new Intent(context, NotificationReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntentCancel = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, notifyID, intentCancel, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManagerCancel = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    if (alarmManagerCancel != null) {
        alarmManagerCancel.cancel(pendingIntentCancel);
        Log.d(TAG, "cancelNotification: notification canceled");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "cancelNotification: nothing to cancel");
    }

}
```

I just cant figure it out what to surround or where to put the Notification Manager so that it wont run the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
```

to

```
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
```

This should stop it from triggering immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys i have found the answer.

It's in the `setNotifData()` method.

```
context.sendBroadcast(_intent);
```

This mistake cost me 2 days -.-.

I got the idea from [here.](https://github.com/shareefhiasat/Code4Reference/blob/master/AndroidProjects/AlarmManagerExample/src/com/rakesh/alarmmanagerexample/AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.java)Silly mistake cost me two days. T_T.